# order items one below another

Tags: html, css

I need to create two labels and select lists:

```
Worker: |______________|
Subcontractor: |______________|
```

But I want to display it better (one select blow the other):

```
Worker:        |______________|
Subcontractor: |______________|
```

I dont want to use tables since this div is inside a table and I don't think this is a good reason to put a table.

How can I do this using html and css?

Comment: Personally I feel this is a good reason to use tables. It's a table of form data ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said earlier in my comment, I feel this is a good reason to use tables. I just found [this article](http://olav.dk/articles/tables.html) which explains it a lot better. It advises against the fixed width solution.

It seems CSS3 might provide a [solution](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid/) in the future. I haven't been following development on [CSS3](http://www.css3.info/), so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

put a label around the first word(s) and give it a specific width.

```
label { width: 3em; }


<label for="this">Contractor</label> <select name="this">...
<label for="that">Subcontrator</label> <select name="that">...
```

Comment: I tried it but I width doesn't effect on labels. I tried it under firefox.

Answer (score 0):

float is the best:

```
label { float:left:margin-right:10px;display:inline;width: 120px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using tables you need to place the first part of the text in a `div` then with css set its width and then also set its float property `float:left`.

Answer (score 0):

you may use containers with appropriate width and align/float the contents.